# Открыть Silverlight приложение в новом окне браузера из под кода

Tags: silverlight, c#

Silverlight приложение встроено в веб-страничку. Нужно по нажатию кнопки в этом приложении, открыть его в отдельном окне браузера. Кто-нибудь знает как?

P.S.: задача максимум - ещё и передать как-то текущее состояние приложения.

Answer (score 2):

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
    new Uri("http://silverlight.net"), 
        "_blank", "menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=0, status=0, toolbar=0, width=500, height=500");
```

Текущее состояние можешь передать get запросом в Uri, если я правильно понял что ты имеешь ввиду.

Подробнее: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc190356(v=VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Ага, спасибо, попробую как приду на работу :)